# Login page in react using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I tried to do sample login page in react using react hooks(`useState()`).
When user is not login I redirect it to home. When I use hooks, that is not being redirected.
**here is my code**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [isLogin, changeLogin] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/" exact activeStyle={{'color':'green'}}>Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/about" activeStyle={{'color':'green'}}>About</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/user/stack" activeStyle={{'color':'green'}}>User Stack</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink to="/user/overflow" activeStyle={{'color':'green'}}>User Overflow</NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input className="loginButton" type="button" value={isLogin ? 'Logout' : 'Login'} onClick={ () => changeLogin(!isLogin)}/>
                <hr/>
                <Route path="/" exact strict render={() => <Home/>} />
                <Route path="/about" exact strict render={() => <About/>} />
                <Route path="/user/:username" exact strict render={({match}) => {
                    return(isLogin ? (<User username={match.params.username}/>) : (<Redirect to="/" />))
                }} component={User} />
            </div>  
        </Router>
    );
}

function Home(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
function About(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
const User = ({match}) => {
    return(<h2>Welcome User {match.params.username}</h2>);
}

export default App;
```

I use `usestate` to handle the state which tells the user is logged in or not. How can I achieve this using react hooks?

Comment: why do you use `render` and `component` props on your Route ? you should remove the `component={User}`, you will find the doc here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods -> `You should use only one of these props on a given <Route>`

Answer (score 0):

Removing `component={User}` on your route should solve the problem :

```
<Route path="/user/:username" exact strict 
       render={({match}) => isLogin ? 
            <User username={match.params.username}/> : 
            <Redirect to="/" />
        } 
 />
```